# How to get route link in Slim3 Twig?

Tags: twig, slim, twig-extension, slim-3

I defined my route so:

```
$app->get('/about', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'about.twig');
})->setName('about.page');
```

I'm interested to get route link by name like: `{% get_route('about.page') %}`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Slim3 there is the `path_for(name)` function. F.ex:

```
{{ path_for('about.page') }}
```

Reference: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html

> The `slim/twig-view` component exposes a custom `path_for()` function to your Twig templates. You can use this function to generate complete URLs to any named route in your Slim application. The `path_for()` function accepts two arguments:
>
> - 1 A route name
> - 2 A hash of route placeholder names and replacement values

Note: The `path_for` uses the function of the router which is `$router->pathFor(..)`

**Why not to use `{%`**

`{%` is a control structur in twig, `Message: Unknown "path_for" tag in "base.twig" at line XX.` is displayed because there is no such tag as control structur defined so twig doesn't know that this is actually a function.
So use the output structur in twig `{{`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Yes.

IIRC

```
{{ path_for('about.page') }}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/blob/master/src/TwigExtension.php#L37

Comment: I get there only `Message: Unknown "path_for" tag in "base.twig" at line 39.` what have I to write as function?

Comment: No, the function is already built in. Check path name spelling.

Comment: @Michelle the function is baked into the Twig-View slim package. https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/blob/master/src/TwigExtension.php#L37